# Datatable multiple checkbox selection - modify selection header

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have datatable with multiple checkbox selection (PF 3.3.1). I've defined column:

```
<p:column selectionMode="multiple"/>
```

I would like add some text or icon to header and I tried with `headerText` column attribute and with facet:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Header text" />
</f:facet>
```

But it doesn't work.
It is possible to modify header of checkbox selection column?

Comment: how about `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" headerText="hello"/>`?

Comment: seems that pf dont support this feature, you always can achieve it with jquery (add some span with text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want that feature badly and don't mind to use jquery, You could do something like

I tested it on [primefaces shocase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf) and it works (run these command at the console)

```
$("<span class='someClass'>Hellow</span>").insertAfter($('#form\\:multiCars thead tr:eq(2) th').find('.ui-chkbox-box'))
```

note that `#form\\:multiCars` should be changed with your table id

and `tr:eq(2)` refers to the third row in the table , cause in showcase the row with the headers is third

to change the width of that selection column you can use

```
$($('#form\\:multiCars thead tr:eq(2) th')[0]).css('width',100)
```

I'm aware of the fact that its waaaay ugly , but it works :)

Also you will have to run this script after each ajax rendering of the table